# What to do if someone answers a question which has been asked already and marked accepted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, duplicate-answers

I have seen there are many question that has been marked as duplicate and even knowing about this, user post their answer to just grab reputation points, instead of just pointing out the URL and marking as a duplicate.

Sometimes due to only single link referred in the *review* question, moderator could not make question as duplicate, so user are posting their answer and making duplication.

Is there any direct action that can be performed on answers that are the same as we are marking a question as duplicate?

Comment: No. Unless plagiarised, there would be no way to tell that the answerer had not come up with that answer themselves. There's no requirement to search for duplicates before answering, so you can only best assume they've done nothing "wrong". If plagiarised, flag for a Moderator with the custom flag.

Comment: It is probably best to dispense with the expectations of the way SO should work for another fat 4 weeks.  It is pretty crazy right now with a massive influx of students working on their end-of-semester assignment.  Asking *and* answering.  If you want help to get a question closed or deleted then you need to post a link.

Comment: @HansPassant, that means I need to post two link with same question and relative same answer in current question??

Comment: No, just the Q is enough.

Comment: If you're pretty sure someone is intentionally answering a dup just to get reputation, and that really bothers you, nothing's stopping you from downvoting them.

Comment: In the really egregious cases, where someone copies and pastes an answer from the duplicate question, or just posts "You should do this: \[link to duplication answer\]", you can flag their answer appropriately, of course.

Comment: @abarnert Is it fine that, just marking that answer as duplicate, and how can I mark ANSWER duplicate, there is no such option while flagging answer.

Comment: If the issue really is them copying and pasting an answer from a duplicate question, or another answer from the same question, you can flag that as plagiarism. If it's just them writing an unnecessary repwhoring answer to a duplicate question, I'd suggest that you just vote to close the question as a duplicate and don't worry about the answer.